# How to make Javascript functions fire after the completion of another function?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, promise

I am looking to fire a series of functions after a few other functions have run and loaded content to my webpage. I have used `setTimeOuts` but I understand it's poor practice given there could be a lag in the connection, in which case they would run incorrectly. How do I do functions sequentially without using `setTimeOuts`.

The `avgEmotion` and `avgSentiment` functions are supposed to run once a series of lists are created on the webpage through the `newsApiLeft()` and `newsApiRight()` functions.

Thanks so much in advance.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var filter = document.getElementById("news_cat");
  var filterSource = document.getElementById("news_source");
  var category = filter.value;
  var source = filterSource.value;
  params.sources = source;
  params.q = category;
  parameters.q = category;

  var filterL = document.getElementById("news_sourceL");
  var sourceL = filterL.value;
  parameters.sources = sourceL;

  showContent();
  clearTextRight();
  clearTextLeft();

  newsApiLeft();
  newsApiRight();

  setTimeout(avgEmotionR, 2000);
  setTimeout(avgEmotionL, 2000);
  setTimeout(avgSentiment, 2000);
})
```

Comment: you can use callbacks, but if you're not comfortable with them, you can take a look at Douglas Crockford's RQ https://github.com/douglascrockford/RQ

Comment: what do  `newsApiLeft` and `newsApiRight` return? I guess they are asynchronous functions. Functions not returning anything and not receiving any parameters is a clear sign of bad code.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to execute a function after another one returns (asynchronous calls) is by using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Make your `newsApiLeft()` and `newsApiRight` functions returning a Promise and then call them like follows:

```js
var newsApiLeft = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // do something long running
  let everythingWasOK = true;

  if (everythingWasOK) {
    resolve("I can return a value");
    //or just resolve();
  } else {
    reject(Error("Or error"));
  }
});

newsApiLeft.then((returnedData)=>{
  avgEmotionL();
  //run another function here;
  //you can use the returnedData
}, (error)=>{
    //optionally handle error
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using JavaScript promises.

Here i created a Promise A, where I do my logic processing at the comment mentioned below. Then you need to either resolve or reject it based on your logic. If you resolve then() function will be called.

In the first then() function you can nest new promise.  Like wise you can nest as many as you want. This way you can make sure promise B will execute only after end of promise A.

```
var A = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    // Do an async task here and then...

    if(/* good condition */) {
        resolve('Success!');
    }
    else {
        reject('Failure!');
    }
});

A.then(function() { 
    /* do something with the result */
}).catch(function() {
    /* error :( */
})
```

For executing promise A just do `A();`

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using callbacks:

```
function newsApiLeft(callback) {
    // Load stuff

    // Then call the callback; the code you want
    //  to run after the loading is complete
    callback();
}

newsApiLeft(function() {
    avgEmotion();
    avgSentiment();
});
```

If you're using the same callback for both `Left` and `Right`, you could save the callback and use it for both:

```
var callback = function() {
    avgEmotion();
    avgSentiment();
}

newsApiLeft(callback);
newsApiRight(callback);
```